# How to define a type-class the returns a value of another type-class

Tags: haskell

How can I say that a monad m is

- An instance of MonadReader
- For which `ask` returns a value belonging to a type-class `HasReadables`
- Such that that type-class in turn define a function returning a value belonging a second `FuncsClass`
- Such that I can call functions in the second type-class, `FuncsClass`
- e.g. `val <- lift (funcs1 . readables1) ask`, where `funcs1` and `readables1` are functions defined in the two type-classes

My *primary problem* is how to make my monadic code entirely independent of the underlying data-types: perhaps I need to consider something other than type-classes.

Here's a sketch of the code

E.g.

```
class FuncsClass f where
   func1 f = ...
   func2 f = ...
   ...
data MyFuncsData = ...
instance FuncsClass MyFuncsData where ...

class HasReadables i where
   readables1 = forall f. FuncsClass f => i -> f
   readables2 = ...
data ReadOnlyData = ReadOnlyData { r1 :: MyFuncsData, etc :: etc }
instance HasReadables ReadOnlyData where ... ** Can't figure this out **

monadFunc :: (MonadReader r m, HasReadables r) => ContreteType -> m OtherType
monadFunc input = 
    val <- liftM (func1 . readables1) ask
    -- do stuff and return
```

---

**Edit 2** You don't need to read the rest of this question to understand the answer below :)

---

**Edit**
So here's my actual problem for those suspecting an XY Problem. I'm writing an adventure game. The monad stack is

```
type AdventureGame = RWS GameInfo GameState GameLog
```

The type `GameLevel` contains the rules of the world. The type `GameInfo` contains `GameLevel` and `PlayerInfo` (name, save-file). The type `GameState` has the mutable state of the world. I want to write

```
goto :: (HasLevel r, MonadReader r m, HasPlayer s, MonadState s m)
     => Direction -> m MoveResult
goto d = do
  src <- liftM (playerLocation) get
  dst <- liftM (locationAt src direction . getLevel) ask
  case dst of
    Nothing  -> return (CantMoveInDirection d)
    (Just l) -> do
      modify (setPlayerLocation l)
      return (EnteredLocation l)
```

The state part of this works. The `HasPlayer` class defines both the `playerLocation` and `setPlayerLocation` functions; it's implemented for a `GameState` type; and a `GameState` value is passed into `runStateT`

The reader part of this fails. The `locationAt` function is defined in a Level type class, and an implementation is provided for `GameLevel`. However `runReaderT` is passed a `GameInfo` type which contains both a `GameLevel` value and `PlayerInfo` value. This indirection means that to make things similarly generic I would like to have something like

```
class HasLevel i where
  getLevel :: forall l. Level l => getLevel :: i -> l

instance HasLevel GameInfo where
  getLevel = giLevel -- ^ giLevel is just a field of GameInfo
```

but this won't compile due to `Could not deduce (l ~ GameLevel)`.

The primary issue, as mentioned in the abstract example above, is how to work around this indirection and keep the monadic code independent of implementation details.

Comment: “perhaps I need to consider something other than type-classes” — indeed. It looks a lot like you try to (ab)use type classes as OO classes here. Don't do that; the proper way (if there is any) to translate OO classes to Haskell is as plain data records with functions (≌ methods) as fields. Inheritance is simply a matter of updating those fields.

Comment: I'm thinking more about OCaml's module system (mod-signature + type+ mod-implementation) than OOP here. I'm just curious can I: (a) make the monadic functions as short as possible by defining business logic in pure code and (b) wholly isolate the monadic code from changes in the underlying data-representation.

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/312922). Give us the context - what you're actually trying to achieve - and we'll be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: I've provided the concrete code in the edit to the main question (initially I tried doing this in comments, but it was unreadable so I deleted them)

Comment: will there ever be more than one thing that is an instance of `HasLevel`? - or simply: why don't you just use a `Level` type/structure? (Obviously same question for the `HasPlayer`/ `Player`)

Comment: In the same way that `goto` uses `HasPlayer` but not, say, `HasInventory` aspects of the `MonadState`, there are some functions that will `HasLevel` and some that will only `HasPlayerInfo` (e.g. a game-save action). I prefer this effects style approach of writing signatures instead of just writing `goto :: Direction -> MysteryMonad MoveResult`. In terms of the level information itself, I can't yet think of any other type I'd use to represent that information: but I'd like to be able to structure my code such that I could opt into a different representation if I wished.

Comment: Just to add, my main query is can I make functions, particularly monadic functions, wholly independent of the underlying data representation. The particular concrete problem I have is accessing one type-class through another type-class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is `TypeFamilies` extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
```

Using it we can add a place-holder, called `FuncsResults` to our `HasReadables` type-class declaration, which will identity the concrete type which each instance will return. We can constrain this placeholder to ensure that whatever type is picked in the instance is itself an instance of the `Funcs` class.

```
class Funcs f where
  func1 :: f -> Int

class (Funcs FuncsResult) => HasReadables r where
  type FuncsResult :: *
  readable1 :: r -> FuncsResult
```

Here are the concrete data-types

```
data FuncsRepr = FuncsRepr {
  returnValue :: Int
}

data Wrapper = Wrapper {
  repr :: FuncsRepr
}
```

And here is how to implement the classes, where we now replace the placeholder `FuncsResult` with an actual concrete type, `FuncsRepr` which is an instance of the `Funcs` class.

```
instance Funcs FuncsRepr where
  func1 = returnValue

instance HasReadables Wrapper where
  type FuncsResult = FuncsRepr
  readable1 = repr
```

The use of this placeholder fixes the ambiguity that previously tripped up the type-inference engine.

And finally here is a sample monadic function

```
monadFunc :: (HasReadables r, MonadReader r m)
          => String -> m String
monadFunc s = do
  val <- liftM (func1 . readable1) ask
  return (s ++ show val)
```

Which we can run

```
runReader 
   (monadFunc "Hello") 
   Wrapper { repr = FuncsRepr { returnValue = 2 } }
```

and obtain the desired result.

```
Hello2
```

Comment: I was waiting to see if anyone could suggest anything wrong with this, or a better solution, but since no-one has, I'll just accept my own answer.